# What are the Agile tools for PHP?

Tags: php

```
- Unit Testing
  - Mocking 
  - Inversion of Control
  - Refactoring
  - Object Relational Mapping
  - Others?
```

I have found [simpletest](http://www.lastcraft.com/simple_test.php) for unit testing and mocking and, though it leaves much to be desired, it kind-of sort of works.

I have yet to find any reasonable Inversion of Control framework (there is one that came up on phpclasses but no documentation and doesn't seem like anyone's tried it).

Answer (score 3):

[phpUnderControl](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/) - continuous integration.

Don't forget about version control (e.g. using [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/))!

Comment: Xinc may be another option for continuous integration. It is more PHP specific. http://sourceforge.net/projects/xinc

Answer (score 1):

Unit Testing - PHPUnit [phpunit.de](http://www.phpunit.de/)

ORM - Doctrine [phpdoctrine.org](http://www.phpdoctrine.org/), Propel [propel.phpdb.org](http://propel.phpdb.org/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rizier123, the question asks for information on agile tools that can be used for PHP. The best way to answer this question is to provide links to these tools. It isn't really possible to include any other "essential parts" in the answer. What would they be?

Answer (score 1):

[Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) is a framework which focuses on Agile development values of producing software quickly then fine-tuning it.